# Python error: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
df_mridula = pd.read_csv ('heart.csv')
X = df_mridula.iloc[:, 1:-1].values
Y = df_mridula.iloc[:, -1].values
#splitting the data 
trainX,testX,trainY,testY =train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.4, shuffle=False)

#splitting the data 
trainX,testX,trainY,testY =train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.4, shuffle=False)
```

when I run this line

`trainX,testX,trainY,testY =train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.4, shuffle=False)`

I get this error. I tried pip install -h5py also but it was not fixed.

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: That function is probably expecting to work with bytes-like objects, not strings. What happens if you encode `X` and `Y` to contain bytes-like objects instead of strings (I'd throw UTF-8 at it first)?

Comment: Trying installing the last version of sklearn. Otherwise a link to the data would be helpful.